# Heap corruption exception when making interop call

Tags: c#, c++, interop

So I'm trying to get some code working in my .net project that was originally written in C++.  I thought the easiest thing would be to simply wrapper it up in a DLL and use pinvoke to get it working.

It seems straightforward, but it throws a heap corruption exception at the same line in the C++ code every time.

```
public class NN_Wrapper 
{

    [DllImport("MyNative.dll", CharSet= CharSet.Ansi)]
    private static extern unsafe int DoWork(DataPoint[] fixedVals, int fixedValsLength, [In, Out]DataPoint[] workVals, int workValsLength);


    public void DoWork(DataPoint[] fixedVals, DataPoint[] workVals)
    {
        DoWork(fixedVals, fixedVals.Length, workVals, workVals.Length);
    }
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public struct DataPoint
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 3)]
    public double[] inputVals;

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 3)]
    public double[] outputVals;
}
```

But about two calls into the DLL, it throws an except,  I've got the source to the DLL as well, this is where it throws the excpetion.

```
vertex *initPoints(double *x, double *y, double *z, 
                   double *u, double *v, double *w, int n)
{
    vertex* ps = new vertex[n];
```

Of course when I run the code in a test C++ project, it executes without issue, what's my mistake?

Comment: Are you pinning those arrays?

Comment: I'm not pinning them. Since they are blittable types do they need to be pinned?

Comment: They should have to yes. Arrays can be moved by the garbage collector. If they are moved whilst in your unmanaged code.. your pointers in unmanaged code are no longer valid.

Comment: The pinvoke marshaller already pins, that's not the problem.  I'd guess at just plain old heap corruption in your C++ code.

Comment: What about the array of the struct @HansPassant?